# VBA - Get last two digits in cell(variable lenght) that are divided by space and copy them

Tags: vba, excel

I have range that has data, single cells looks like this

"3100021 DATATEXT - IM03051718 100 101"

Need is to break data down to different cells.
I`m looking into efficient way of findind how long is last number and number before it, to copy it and use in different cells.

Reason I`m asking is that those numbers can be 1, 2 or 3 digits.
For example:

3100031 DATATEXT - IM03051718 6 12

3100041 DATATEXT- IM03051718 122 0

I was thinking of using bunch of If scenarios, but that`s not really efficient.

PS. I`m just looking for a way to define those 2 numbers in the end and assign them to a variable, the easy cut/copy/paste stuff I can handle.

Thank you for looking into this, all help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not use len() with find() and look for the space at position 4 from rhs etc

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for gettin on this, how do I set up find to look from rhs?

Comment: Well why not start with find(“ “,a1,len(a1)-4) and if that gives a result then use right(a1, len(a1)-3) to bring back the number of 3 digits - can’t test anything as on a smartphone, but check out functions like left() mid() find() right()... and if you copy paste my examples check the double quotes are correct...

Comment: okay, great, let me dig, I will let you know.

Comment: @Ivan - can you please [edit] you question to specify what the result would be on each of the examples in your question?

Comment: @ivan - If the output for the first example would be `100 101` see the **bottom** of **[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431682/8112776)**.  Otherwise *any* of the other functions in my answer will work to return the "last word" (everything after the last space).

Comment: @ashleedawg - yes, output should be 100 101, I`ve specified in the question as well now, thanks for noticing, was not really clear there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I written ahother approach to handle your problem, necessary comments are in code:

```
Sub Extract()
    Dim cellVal As String, splitted() As String
    Dim secondToLast As String, last As String
    'read vaslue from worksheet
    cellVal = Cells(1, 1).Value
    'split by space to get single numbers/parts of a string
    splitted = Split(cellVal, " ")
    'access to last numbers
    secondToLast = splitted(UBound(splitted) - 1)
    last = splitted(UBound(splitted))
End Sub
```

It's straightforward, IMO cleaner and more efficient than already given answer :)

Comment: this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

*Welcome to [so]!*

This function will return whatever's after the last space in a cell or string:

```
Function lastWord(st As String)
    lastWord=Split(st)(UBound(Split(st)))
End Function
```

It can be used as a worksheet function or in VBA.

[image: img]

---

This function gives the **exact same** result, a **completely different** way:

```
Function lastword2(st As String)
    lastword2=Mid(st,InStrRev(st," ")+1)
End Function
```

...and another: (this one based on @SolarMike's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431569/vba-get-last-two-digits-in-cellvariable-lenght-that-are-divided-by-space-and/50431682#comment87877638_50431569))

```
Function lastword3(st As String)
    lastword3 = Mid(st, InStr(Len(st) - 3, st, " "))
End Function
```

There are several other ways to accomplish the same thing.

The lesson being, with most tasks in Excel/VBA, there are numerous ways to accomplish the same task, so of one isn't working, take a few steps back and rethink your overall goal (as opposed to getting stuck on a single idea).

---

## EDIT

If it's actually the "last 2 words" you need, a small modification to each function also does the trick:

```
Function last2Words(st As String) As String
    last2Words = Split(st)(UBound(Split(st)) - 1) & _
        "/" & Split(st)(UBound(Split(st)))
End Function
```

[image: img]

Comment: @pnuts "last number and number before it", it's definitely the pairs that you specified.

Comment: @pnuts So everything after the 2nd-to-last space?  I interpreted "number" as "digit", not as "groups".

Comment: Hi all, thanks for suggestions, I managed to define last number using example above:
 number1 = Mid(cell, InStrRev(cell, " ") + 1)
Let me try other samples! Thanks for help! Will let you know how`d go.

Answer (score 0):

RegExp would work really well here.

Check `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` under Tools>References... in the Excel VBA editor.

I set up a sample in a worksheet that looks like this:

[Excel Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NzdF.png)

And I ran the code below:

```
Sub LastTwoNumbers()
  Dim MySheet As Worksheet
  Dim MatchCell As Range
  Dim CellText As String
  Dim Regex As New RegExp
  Dim Pattern As String
  Dim AllMatches As Object
  Dim MyMatches(0 To 1) As String

  Set MySheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

  Dim X As Integer
  For X = 1 To 5
    Set MatchCell = MySheet.Cells(X, 1)
    CellText = MatchCell.Text

    Pattern = "(\d*) (\d*)$"
    Regex.Pattern = Pattern
    Set AllMatches = Regex.Execute(CellText)

    If AllMatches.Count <> 1 Then
      Debug.Print "Whoops"
    Else
      MyMatches(0) = AllMatches(0).SubMatches(0)
      MyMatches(1) = AllMatches(0).SubMatches(1)
    End If

    Debug.Print MyMatches(0)
    Debug.Print MyMatches(1)
  Next X
End Sub
```

My final printed output for the code was:

```
100
101
10
101
1
101
100
10
100
1
```

This works by using the pattern string to target two groups of variable length of digits at the end of your cell's text. In `Pattern`, `(\d*)` means a group `()` of at least one digit `\d*`, and the `$` means the match needs to come at the end of the string. The space between the two `(\d*)`'s is interpreted as a literal.

Answer (score -1):

Using the creative way once offered by @m4573r; you may first find the position of the last space and then can find the last number using this position:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","☃",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))
```

The credit should go [here](https://superuser.com/questions/680769/i-need-to-find-the-last-space-in-a-xls-cell) for the `FIND` portion. And the breakdown of that part is also explained at that link.

The rest basically uses this last space position to find out how many characters should we rip of from the right of the string.

Comment: that is indeed a very good compilation, thanks for bringing it up!